# Textbox multiline ability without adding a newline

Tags: c#, wpf, multiline

I would like to be able to copy-and-paste multiple lines of text (multiline) to my textbox, without the ability to insert a newline from the ENTER key.

I have set `AcceptsReturn="True"` in the form and, in the KeyUp handler, removed newline characters when the ENTER key was pressed using Regex:
`TextBox1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(TextBox1, @"\t|\n|\r", "");`

Is there a better method that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to accept <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then remove it.
You can just handle `PreviewKeyDown` event and if Key is <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then `e.handled = true;`.

Comment: Yes `e.handled = true` is best solution for your scenario.